# Are second-countable subsets of topological vector spaces metrizable?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological vector space of size $\mathfrak{c}$. Assume that there exists a countable union $X=\cup X_n$ such that all *subsets* $X_n$'s are relatively second countable.

Q. Does there exists a a countable union $X=\cup Y_n$ such that all $Y_n$'s are relatively second countable metrisable?

Comment: If $X_n$ is second-countable, then so are all subsets of $X_n$. Also second-countable $T_1$-spaces have cardinality at most $\mathfrak{c}$, so your hypothesis is redundant.

Comment: Wikipedia helps here a lot: [Metrization theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrization_theorem), the [Bing matrization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bing_metrization_theorem), the [Nagata-Smirnov metrization theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagata%E2%80%93Smirnov_metrization_theorem).

Comment: @Alex M. Thanks a lot, valuable information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows from general facts.

- [Topological vector spaces are (completely) regular](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2332760/every-topological-vector-space-is-regular).
- Subspaces of regular spaces are regular.
- A second-countable space is metrisable if and only if it is regular (see Theorems 32.1, 32.2, and 34.1 in Munkres' *Topology*).